# clock Time on x-axis in matlab

Tags: matlab, time, plot

I need some help related to plots in MATLAB.

I want to plot my data with respect to clock time on x-axis. I have an occupancy information data for every 15 minutes interval. I want to plot it against time. How can i do it? The problem is with the x-axis, how can i handle time and uniform intervals e.g data is of the form

```
data=[1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 .............]
```

value of time is from 9 AM to 9 PM and the interval is 15 minutes

How can i set the intervals on the x-axis?

Thank you

Comment: Easiest way: define yourself a time vector: `timeSpan=9:0.25:21`Using a 24h system its quite easy. Otherwise it becomes more difficult since your data would jump back to 0.25 after passing 12 O´clock. The definition is equal to go from 9 to 21 in steps of 0.25. If you have longer times think about using the elapsed time as x-scale. But honestly this isn't solving the problem but ignoring it ;)

Answer (score 0):

The following code solves the problem. you enter Integer values for starting hour and minute, the ending time and the time steps between the measurements. Further enter/change the `steps_x` value. This shows how many time values are skipped on the x-axis. `7=skip6` values. Below the `for-loop` is my y-data. I just used `random-function`. 
The resulting x-axis is a cell-array. This could be a problem for some applications. Further I used some 'unneccessary' variables. These i used for verifing my code. I didn't change it, because i thought that it would be easier to understand that way. 
 
The biggest problem of my so

```
clc; clear all; close all;
%%//Variable declaration
start_hour = 9; %in hours
start_min = 5;     %//in minutes
steps_min = 10;    %//in minutes
end_hour = 21.0;   %//in hours
end_min= 0;        %//in minutes
steps_x = 7;       %//how many times are displayed on the axis, doesn't change data

%%// code for computing internal values, steps and transforming to am/pm
%//changes the entries above to hour display(9.75=9h45min)
start_time= (start_hour+start_min/60); 
%//changes the entries above to hour display(9.75=9h45min)
end_time=(end_hour+end_min/60); 
%//changes steps to hour
steps_hour= steps_min/60;             
%//array of hours
mytest_timeline = start_time:steps_hour:end_time;
%//array of minutes(copied and modified from @natan)
mytest_minutes = mod((0:steps_min:(steps_min*(length(mytest_timeline)-1)))+start_min,60);
%//cell array for am/pm display
mytest_timeline_ampm = num2cell(mytest_timeline); 
%//if hour is smaller 12 write am otherwise pm
for k=1:length(mytest_timeline); 
    if mytest_timeline(k) < 12
        mytest_ampm = {'am'}; 
        %//converting the down rounded hour to str
        helper_hour=num2str(mod(floor(mytest_timeline(k)),12));
        %//converting the minute to str and giving it 2 digits eg. 05 for 5min
        helper_minute = num2str(mytest_minutes(k),'%02d'); 
        %//joining strings
        mytest_timeline_ampm(k)= strcat(helper_hour,{'.'}, helper_minute, mytest_ampm);
    %//same as for am just for pm
    else 
        mytest_ampm = {'pm'};
        helper_hour=num2str(mod(floor(mytest_timeline(k)),12));
        helper_minute = num2str(mytest_minutes(k),'%02d');
        mytest_timeline_ampm(k)= strcat(helper_hour,{'.'}, helper_minute, mytest_ampm);
    end
end 

%%// generated y data so that i could test the code
mytest_y = rand(size(mytest_timeline)); 

%%// changing display
%//x-coordinates(for displaying x,y)
mytest_x= 1:length(mytest_timeline); 
%//x-axis label
mytest_x_axis = 1:steps_x:length(mytest_timeline); 
%//plots the data mytest_y in uniform distances (mytest_x)
plot(mytest_x, mytest_y, 'b')
%//changes the x-label accordingly to mytest_x_axis to the am/pm timeline
set(gca, 'XTick',mytest_x_axis, 'XTickLabel',mytest_timeline_ampm(mytest_x_axis))
```